# vtkRenderWindow off-screen rendering

Tags: c++, vtk, fbo

I would like to do off-screen rendering of vtkRenderWindow into the frame buffer object.

I'm not sure how to do so, but what I think is that:

1. generate frame buffer using **glGenFramebuffers** - obtain **GLuint fbo_id**
2. create **vtkFrameBufferObject** from **vtkRendererWindow** (I don't know how to do so)
3. call **SetActiveBuffer**(fbo_id) on **vtkFrameBufferObject**
4. call **RenderQuad** on **vtkFrameBufferObject** -> now the created FBO should be filled with data.

My question is - how can I create **vtkFrameBufferObject** with the contents of my window, so I can do the off-screen rendering into the FBO ? Should this be done as I stated above ?